# Multiple Magento Installation

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account

I would like to have multiple Magento installation for my company, because I want to put the installations on different server in the world, but I would like to ba able to login on all installations with the same login.

Do you know how I can share the Customer Informations between multiple Magento installation?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it you have few options:

1. Share same database but put files in different servers with different domains pointing to your installations. This is probably what you are looking for. You would need to setup multistore in magento. Refer to [this](https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2-x/Sharing-database-for-two-websites/td-p/59319) discussion for more info.
2. Separate databases automated import and export.
3. Separate databases with middleware or API connector.
4. One website with multistore setup. this is probably best option. I mean for speed and ease of managment. Use CDN if you need speed enhancment in far away parts of the world.

But I have never done this myself so test before production.